# HystrixRuntimeException : timed-out and no fallback available.] with root cause java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null

Tags: spring-boot, hystrix, feign

I am continuously getting HystrixTimeOut exception when invoking another microservice via feign.
I have read all the soultions on StackOverFlow and github community but nothing worked for me.

below is my configuration:

```
hystrixProperties:
  hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 6000000
```

code

```
@FeignClient(value = "some-service", decode404 = true)
public interface UserClient extends UserUtil {

  @GetMapping("/names")
  ResponseEntity<UserResponse> getUserData(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String tokenKey);
```

Exception:

```
04-12-2020 12:37:16.459 [https-jsse-nio-20104-exec-6] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet].log - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: UserClient#getUserData(String) timed-out and no fallback available.] with root cause
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.handleTimeoutViaFallback(AbstractCommand.java:997)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.access$500(AbstractCommand.java:60)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:609)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$12.call(AbstractCommand.java:601)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$4.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:140)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onError(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:87)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$1.run(AbstractCommand.java:1142)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:41)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable$1.call(HystrixContextRunnable.java:37)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:57)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:1159)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:99)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

My calling service is able to reach called(User) service. User service is also completing the processing very fast and returning the data. Issue is I am getting exception at my calling service.

Please help me